# PYMongo : Parsing|Serializing query output of a collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

By default `collection.find` or `collection.findone()` functions results in a dictionary types and if you pass paramater `as_class=SomeUserClass` than it will try to parse the result into this class format.
but it seems this class should also be derived class of dictionary (as it required `__setitem__` function to be defined and i can add keys in the class ).
Here i want to set the properties of the class. how can i do achieve this?
Also, my collection class contains some child classes as properties .So how can i set the properties of child classes also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by adding `__setitem__` in class. 
than i do

```
result = as_class()
for key,value in dict_expr.items():
        result.__setitem__(key,value)
```

and in my class `__setitem__` is like

```
def __setitem__(self,key,value):
     try:
        attr = getattr(class_obj,key)
        if(attr!=None):
            if(isinstance(value,dict)):
                for child_key,child_value in value.items(): 
                    attr.__setitem__(child_key,child_value)
                setattr(class_obj,key,attr)
            else:
                setattr(class_obj,key,value)

    except AttributeError:
       pass
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like an object-relational mapper. I am the primary author of one [Ming](http://sf.net/projects/merciless) , but there exist several others for Python as well. In Ming, you might do the following to set up your mapping:

```
from ming import schema, Field
from ming.orm import (mapper, Mapper, RelationProperty, 
    ForeignIdProperty)

WikiDoc = collection(‘wiki_page', session,
    Field('_id', schema.ObjectId()),
    Field('title', str, index=True),
    Field('text', str))
CommentDoc = collection(‘comment', session,
    Field('_id', schema.ObjectId()),
    Field('page_id', schema.ObjectId(), index=True),
    Field('text', str))

class WikiPage(object): pass
class Comment(object): pass

ormsession.mapper(WikiPage, WikiDoc, properties=dict(
    comments=RelationProperty('WikiComment')))
ormsession.mapper(Comment, CommentDoc, properties=dict(
    page_id=ForeignIdProperty('WikiPage'),
    page=RelationProperty('WikiPage')))

Mapper.compile_all()
```

Then you can query for some particular page via:

```
pg = WikiPage.query.get(title='MyPage')
pg.comments # loads comments via a second query from MongoDB
```

The various ODMs I know of for MongoDB in Python are listed below.

- [Ming](http://sf.net/projects/merciless)
- [MongoKit](http://namlook.github.com/mongokit/)
- [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org/)

Comment: I should also mention that you can set the type of a field in your Ming validator, so if you wanted to use a custom dict-to-object converter you could do so by writing a custom ming.schema.SchemaItem.